# Unable to properly access variables within a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to generate a temp folder and file name. And then would like to remove and create the temp folder. Later some files will be copied into that temp folder. Here is my code... (with the help from codes of peers)

```
   echo off
   Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "ZipFileName = png_%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.zip"
   set "TEMPFOLDER = %date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
   echo !TEMPFOLDER!
   set "TEMPDIR =C:\Temp\%ZipFileName%"
   rmdir "%TEMPDIR%"
   mkdir "%TEMPDIR%"
   copy *.png "%TEMPDIR%"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use " in the wromg place and use to much spaces especially around your variable names.

```
set var = somevar with a space
set var= somvar withoit a space
```

Now you have two vars, onen named `var[space]` and one named `var`. You can verify bu using `set v` yo list environment variables.

```
   set ZipFileName=png_%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.zip
   set TEMPFOLDER="%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
   echo !TEMPFOLDER!
   set TEMPDIR="C:\Temp\%ZipFileName%"
   rmdir %TEMPDIR%
   mkdir %TEMPDIR%
   copy *.png %TEMPDIR%
```